# Windows Components section is missing from my Add/Remove Programs

Tags: windows, group-policy, control-panel

I'm guessing it's a group policy thing, because I have to run appwiz.cpl from cmd to launch the add / remove programs window. 
Is there a command line utility to control windows components? If not, how do I edit my policy to let me see the windows components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check: [How to add or remove Windows Components by using Sysocmgr.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222444).
<sup>also look at [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/6037a458-0855-4dbf-8376-e311661aa3ad).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/command-line-shortcut-to-windows-components-wizard) may also help:

start > run > %windir%\system32\sysocmgr.exe /i:%windir%\inf\sysoc.inf

Answer (score 0):

If it is disabled by group policy you can go to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Uninstall
```

Change the `NoWindowsSetupPage` value to 0.